# kubernetes file system size is not being updated after helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'd like to upgrade some values in kubernetes cluster.

I am trying to update the values using values file (storageBackupCluster = 150 and storageRepo: 150Gi , circled in red in the picture below) with the next command:

```
helm upgrade cbur-master /<my_dir>/cbur*  --reset-values -f /<my_dir>/cbur-master.values --recreate-pods --home <my_dir>/helm_home --set storageBackupCluster=150Gi --set storageRepo=150Gi""
```

[cbur-master.values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4qhQ.png)

Persistent volume claims (pvc) are being update (120 to 150):

[PVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXWov.png)

But inside the cluster file system , the size remain the same
as before running the command (120 and not 150):

[file system size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OgJX.png)

How can I also update the file system size?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Where do you run your cluster? What kind of `provisioner` is used? Can be checked running `kubectl get storageclasses`. Also check `kubectl describe sc %name_of_storage_class`, I'm interested in `AllowVolumeExpansion` flag. You can update your question with this information.

Comment: Helm doesn't usually understand PNG files; you need to pass text-format YAML files in as the templates and the values files.  Can you edit the question to include the information necessary to demonstrate the problem, as text (not images) and directly in the question (not behind links)?